# Find $a_{n+2}+3a_{n+1}+2a_n=3^n$ if $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$, and prove

Tags: proof-verification, recurrence-relations

**Find $a_{n+2}+3a_{n+1}+2a_n=3^n$ if $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$, and prove the result.**

---

What I have done:

First we have to find the homogeneous recurrence relation solution, so $$a_{n+2}+3a_{n+1}+2a_n=0\implies x^2+3x+2=0\implies x=-1\vee x=-2,$$ thus $$a_n^H=A(-1)^n+B(-2)^n,\quad A,B\in\Bbb R.$$ Then, we have to propose a particular solution, namely $$a_n^P=K3^n,\quad K\in\Bbb R,$$ since it is linearly independent with the term independent of the original recurrence relation. So if we plug it into the equation, we have \begin{align*}3^n&=K3^{n+2}+3K3^{n+1}+2K3^n\\&=9K3^n+9K3^n+2K3^n\\&=(20K)3^n,\end{align*} so $20K=1$, thus $K=1/20$. Hence, $a_n^P=(1/20)3^n$. Hence, the general solution is $$a_n=a_n^H+a_n^P=A(-1)^n+B(-2)^n+\frac1{20}3^n.$$ To find the particular solution we will use the initial conditions: $$\begin{cases}a_0=0\\a_1=1\end{cases}\equiv\begin{cases}A+B+1/20=0\\-A-2B+3/20=1\end{cases}\implies A=\frac34\wedge B=-\frac45.$$ Therefore, the particular solution (the full answer) is $$\boxed{a_n=\frac34(-1)^n-\frac45(-2)^n+\frac1{20}3^n}.$$ In order to prove this solution, we will use complete induction.

The base step is $a_0=3/4-4/5+1/20=0$ and $a_1=-3/4+8/5+3/20=1$, hence it is true.

$\color{blue}{\text{The inductive step is as follows. Assume it is true for $n$. Then}}$ $$\require{cancel}\xcancel{\begin{align*}
a_{n+2}+3a_{n+1}+2a_n&=\left(\frac34(-1)^{n+2}-\frac45(-2)^{n+2}+\frac1{20}3^{n+2}\right)+3\left(\frac34(-1)^{n+1}-\frac45(-2)^{n+1}+\frac1{20}3^{n+1}\right)+2\left(\frac34(-1)^n-\frac45(-2)^n+\frac1{20}3^n\right)\\
&=\frac34(-1)^n-\frac{16}5(-2)^n+\frac9{20}3^n-\frac94(-1)^n+\frac{24}5(-2)^n+\frac9{20}3^n+\frac32(-1)^n-\frac85(-2)^n+\frac1{10}3^n\\
&=\left(\frac34-\frac94+\frac32\right)(-1)^n+\left(-\frac{16}5+\frac{24}5-\frac85\right)(-2)^n+\left(\frac9{20}+\frac9{20}+\frac1{10}\right)3^n\\
&=3^n,
\end{align*}}$$
$$\color{blue}{\begin{align*}
a_{(n+1)+2}+3a_{(n+1)+1}+2a_{n+1}&=\left(\frac34(-1)^{n+3}-\frac45(-2)^{n+3}+\frac1{20}3^{n+3}\right)+3\left(\frac34(-1)^{n+2}-\frac45(-2)^{n+2}+\frac1{20}3^{n+2}\right)+2\left(\frac34(-1)^{n+1}-\frac45(-2)^{n+1}+\frac1{20}3^{n+1}\right)\\
&=-\frac34(-1)^n+\frac{32}5(-2)^n+\frac{27}{20}3^n+\frac94(-1)^n-\frac{48}5(-2)^n+\frac{27}{20}3^n-\frac64(-1)^n+\frac{16}(-2)^n
+\frac3{10}3^n\\
&=\left(-\frac34+\frac94-\frac32\right)(-1)^n+\left(\frac{32}5-\frac{48}5+\frac{16}5\right)(-2)^n+\left(\frac{27}{20}+\frac{27}{20}+\frac3{10}\right)3^n\\
&=(3)3^n\\
&=3^{n+1},
\end{align*}}$$ hence it is true for $n+1$.

**Is it correct?** I do not think so, since I am not able to see how to apply the inductive step i.e. $n+1$, since there is $a_{\color{red}{n+2}}$, $a_{\color{red}{n+1}}$ and $a_{\color{red}n}$.

$\color{red}{\text{ADDED.}}$ Another question. If we have to prove that our solution satisfies the recurrence relation, **do we ALWAYS have to replace the *particular solution* (if initial conditions are given) and repace the *general solution* if there are not initial conditions?**

Thanks!!

$\color{blue}{\text{Added.}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how to do proof by induction in this case. First we assume that the formula is true for some $k$ and $k+1$ where $k \in\mathbb{N}$. Then we have from the formula found:
$$a_k=\frac34(-1)^k-\frac45(-2)^k+\frac1{20}3^k$$
$$a_{k+1}=\frac34(-1)^{k+1}-\frac45(-2)^{k+1}+\frac1{20}3^{k+1}$$
By using the original recurrence relation we can get $a_{k+2}$;
$$a_{k+2}=3^{k}-3a_{k+1}-2a_k$$
$$=3^{k}-3(\frac34(-1)^{k+1}-\frac45(-2)^{k+1}+\frac1{20}3^{k+1})-2(\frac34(-1)^k-\frac45(-2)^k+\frac1{20}3^k)$$
$$=3^k(1-\frac{9}{20}-\frac{2}{20})+(-2)^k(-\frac{24}{5}+\frac{8}{5})+(-1)^k(\frac{9}{4}-\frac{6}{4})$$
$$=3^k(\frac{9}{20})+(-2)^k(-\frac{16}{5})+(-1)^k(\frac{3}{4})$$
$$=3^{k+2}(\frac{1}{20})-(-2)^{k+2}(\frac{4}{5})+(-1)^{k+2}(\frac{3}{4})$$
$$=\frac34(-1)^{k+2}-\frac45(-2)^{k+2}+\frac1{20}3^{k+2}$$
Thus, if it is true for some $k$ and $k+1$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$, it is also true for $k+2$. As you have proven it is true for $k=0$ and $k+1=1$, it must be true for all positive integers by induction.

Comment: Thank you!! Could you check the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ edit, please? Now is it correct?

Comment: And, if possible, could you answer the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ edit, please?

Comment: That still does not use proof by induction, it simply proves that the formula satisfies the original recurrence relation. For example, we could do the exact same working but using $\frac{1}{20}\cdot 3^n$ instead.

Comment: I do not understand. I supposed that the formula is valid for $n$ and then I prove that is valid for $n+1$, hence the inductive step is true.

Comment: But a proof by induction for a second order recurrence relation requires that it is assumed to be true for some $k$ and some $k+1$. One cannot prove this by induction with a single assumption.

Comment: https://youtu.be/yBbKFSLHlFw?t=869

Comment: Thank you so much, very clear!! $\ddot\smile$.